# How to replace particle-js with static background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

I have no prior experience in HTML, CSS, and javascript.

I'm trying to deploy Particle theme from Jekyll (https://github.com/nrandecker/particle).
And I'd like to change the js background (which is an animation) into a static image that I uploaded to "/assets/img/".

The following is header.html where the background shows up:

```
<div id="particles-js">
  <div class="header">
      <h1>
        <span class="site-title">{{site.username}}</span>
        <span class="site-description">{{site.user_title}}</span>
      </h1>
      <div class="header-icons">
        <a aria-label="Send email" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
        <a aria-label="My Twitter" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a aria-label="My Google Plus" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a aria-label="My Github" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-github-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-links">
        <a class="link" href="#about" data-scroll>About Me</a>
        <a class="link" href="#projects" data-scroll>Projects</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <a class="down" href="#about" data-scroll><i class="icon fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

So the part I'd like to modify is the first line.
As far as I googled, I added .main-header in "/src/styles/_header.css" with some background-img property then replace this 'particles-js' with 'main-header'. But it seems not working.

I think it might be really simple for someone used to.

It would be really appreciated if you could please give advice.

Thanks

Comment: Okay..! do you want the particle effect or not?

Comment: @Anglesvar Cheenu I don't! I just want to remove this animation and put my own image instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want, try to remove `<div id="particles-js">` and the closing tag of this as well, and instead add

`<div style="background: url("/assets/img/your-image.png")">`

Read this article https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-add-a-background-image-located-in-the-computer-in-a-HTML-page-using-CSS.

And, I personally would suggest you, to run the file hosted locally (Localhost).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the part as you and the article said, ran on the localhost but it seems not working as well.